# Build Spark application against runtime classpath of DataStax Enterprise

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I have DataStax Enterprise 4.8 with Spark. I want to build a Spark application written in Scala using Gradle and run it on this DSE cluster but I would like to avoid any classpath issues at runtime.

Currently my compile-time dependencies (and conflict resolutions) are automatically managed by Gradle which has already caused various issues at runtime.

What is the standard way? I want to avoid building a fat-jar which includes all dependencies.

Comment: *Currently my compile-time dependencies (and conflict resolutions) are automatically managed by Gradle which has already caused various issues at runtime.* The standard way is to fix those runtime conflicts to allow you to build a fat-jar which is easier to deploy.

Comment: The problem is that the only thing I know about runtime JARs are their names.

Comment: Do you know which JARs are causing issues? More specifically, can you see at compile time which classes conflict?

Comment: I am trying to avoid this trial-error process. That doesn't sound "standard" to me at all. I want to be absolutely sure that my compile time classpath is the same as runtime classpath.

Comment: How else would you know which classes have versioning issues? I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: I definitely can see ClassDefNotFound errors and other. The question is how to build my application so that I am sure that there will be no classpath-related issues at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

I just would use the libraries provided by the `dse spark-classpath` command. I would incorporate this into the build file like

For SBT

```
val sparkClasspathStr = s"$DSE_HOME/bin/dse spark-classpath".!!.trim
val sparkClasspathArr = sparkClasspathStr.split(':')

//Find all Jars on dse spark-classpath
val sparkClasspath = {
  for ( dseJar <- sparkClasspathArr if dseJar.endsWith("jar"))
    yield Attributed.blank(file(dseJar))
}.toSeq

//Your dependencies
//libraryDependencies += "com.github.scopt" %% "scopt" % "3.2.0"

//Add dse jars to classpath
unmanagedJars in Compile ++= sparkClasspath
unmanagedJars in Test ++= sparkClasspath
```

Gradle

```
def DSE_HOME = (System.getenv("DSE_HOME") != null) ? System.getenv("DSE_HOME") : System.getenv("HOME")+"dse"

def sparkClasspathStr = (DSE_HOME + "/bin/dse spark-classpath").execute().text.trim()
def sparkClasspathJars = sparkClasspathStr.split(":").findAll{ it.endsWith(".jar") }

dependencies {
    compile files(sparkClasspathJars)
}
```

Comment: That helps a little bit, but it still doesn't solve issues with conflicting transitive dependencies. I mean case when my project uses a library A which depends on B version 2, but DSE spark-classpath contains B version 1. In fact I don't even know that there is B on the spark-classpath, because DSE doesn't provide POM files for those JARs. The only thing I know are file names and I can only guess group and artifact names. POM file for all JARs on the spark-classpath would be very helpful. I also assume that all JARs are available on Maven central.

Comment: Hmm, i'm not sure we provide a Pom version at the moment but almost all of the libraries are available on maven central. There are a few deps which are DSE proprietary but they shouldn't be an issue. Usually when incorporating third party libs I attempt to build the fat Jar but I understand you can easily run into transitive issues if you have Guava or Netty.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a at least a list of all DSE proprietary JARs? So that I don't spend a lot of time trying to find them in a public repo.